# unexpected token error line 41-"y:Math.round(Math.random()*(h-cw)/cw);"

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to re-create the classic mobile game "Snake" using HTML/CSS3 and Javascript. When I run what I have in chrome I get the unexpected token error on line 41. Why is the semi-colon unexpected? The code I have so far is below.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    //define vars
    var canvas = $('#canvas')[0];
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var w = canvas.width();
    var h = canvas.height();
    var cw = 15;
    var d = "right";
    var food;
    var score;
    var speed = 130;

    //Snake Array
    var snake_array;

   //initalizer
   function init(){
   create_snake();
   create_food();
   score = 0;

   if(typeof game_loop != "undefined") clearInterval(game_loop);
   game_loop = setInterval(paint, speed);
   }

   init();

   function create_snake(){
   var length = 5;
   snake_array =[];
   for(var i = length-1;i >=0;i--){
   snake_array.push({x: i,y :0});
   }
   }


   //Create Food
   function create_food(){
   food = {
   x:Math.round(Math.random()*(w-cw)/cw),
   y:Math.round(Math.random()*(h-cw)/cw); // <-- line 41
   };
   }




   });



   HTML CODE
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
   <title>Snake Game</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
   </head>
   <body>


   <div class="container">
   <div id ="overlay">
   Your final score: <span id = "final_score">
   </span>
   <br>
   <a onclick="window.location.reload()" href="#">Click to play again!</a>

   </div>

   <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400">

   </canvas>

   <div id="stats">
   <div class="score"></div>
   <div class="score"></div>
   <button onclick="resetScore()" id="reset_score">Reset high score</button>

   </div>

   </div>




   <!-- JQuery -->
   <script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <!-- Main JS -->
   <script src="C:\Users\student\Desktop\SnakeGame\script.js"></script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: I think the answer is simply "because that's how the syntax is defined" - I notice you didn't use a semi-colon when defining the dictionary at the line `snake_array.push({x: i,y :0});`.

Comment: remove the semicolon here: `y:Math.round(Math.random()*(h-cw)/cw);`

Answer (score 1):

When defining a variable like this `x:` (typically used in objects) you cannot put a `;` after the last defined variable like you did:

```
food = {
   x:Math.round(Math.random()*(w-cw)/cw),
   y:Math.round(Math.random()*(h-cw)/cw); // <-- remove this semi-colon 
};
```

Do this instead

```
food = {
   x:Math.round(Math.random()*(w-cw)/cw),
   y:Math.round(Math.random()*(h-cw)/cw)
};
```

I hope I was to any help :3

Comment: Thank you. I made the change you suggested and I received a new error saying "Uncaught TypeError: canvas.width is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>". I included my html code at the bottom of the script code.

Comment: oh I see... when defining "w" and "h" ... canvas.height and canvas.width is not a function. Just do it like this `var w = canvas.width;
    var h = canvas.height;`